# cshtml TextBoxFor should only accept numbers(0-10)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have a textbox, in a table. i.e,

I have to only allow numbers in textbox, and I am trying to do as below.

But, (`+` and `-` and `.`) symbols are being accepted in the textbox( Ex: "+123", "-123", ".123") though I am doing `@type="number"`

Any help would be appreciated.

**My code**

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Amount, new { @id = "amount", @type = "number"})</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unobtrusivevalidation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript) for this case.

After you add scripts and change `Web.Config` you should just annotate your model property:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
   [Range(typeof(int), "0", "10", ErrorMessage = "{0} can only be between {1} and {2}")]
   public int Amount { get; set; }
   /* other properties */
}
```

And then if you write just like this:

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Amount)</td>
```

Razor will create `input` with client validation.